# Correct way to reset jScrollPane viewport position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscrollpane

I've been looking around for answers and everything I apply to my own code doesn't seem to work. I have a DIV with content. When I click on a link the DIV fades out, the content changes via the jQuery .html event and then the DIV fades back in. This gives the illusion of a gentle page change on my site. This DIV has a jScrollPane which works fine before any links are pressed.

What is happening however is that the scroll pane 'draggable area' stays the same size when the content is re-written and there is more or less, or even if there is no need for one at all.

**I need to get the scroll pane 'draggable area' to change size in relation to the new content and I need it to scroll back to the top inbetween the .fadeTo fade out and in effect.**

I've tried some of the following:

```
function showhome() {
        $('#infohome').stop(true,true).fadeTo(100,0)
        $('#infohome').delay(100).html("NEW CONTENT")
        $('#infohome').stop(true,true).delay(200).fadeTo(100,1)
        refreshNav();

function refreshNav() {
        var element = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({scrollToY(0, animate)});
        var api = element.data('jsp');

}
```

As well as:

```
myJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollbar().setValue(int Pos);
```

and a few others.

As always, any help would be greatly appreciated.